# How do you set a custom http client in Bravado?

Tags: python, swagger

I'm using Bravado 3.0.0. I want to make a request that will use my own custom CA Bundle. The underlying Requests client isn't taking advantage of the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` env var I've set.

How do I pass in a custom client that uses my CA Bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer is based on the current-as-of-this-writing 8.1.0 version of Bravado)

Since it took me a while to even find this answer while learning about Bravado, and mostly because I think others might benefit when starting out, here's an updated look into how to establish a connection:

In order to leverage non-default settings in the HTTP client, (using Requests as an example,) one has to create a new HTTP client instance with it's own settings, then pass this to the SwaggerClient.from_url() call:

```
""" Required to create a new Requests 'http_client' instance: """
from bravado.requests_client import Requestsclient
""" Required to create a Bravado SwaggerClient instance: """
from bravado.client import SwaggerClient

""" Create a new Requests client instance: """
http_client = RequestsClient()
```

From here you can do all the fun stuff that Requests allows you to do, like set basic HTTP authentication:

```
http_client.set_basic_auth(SERVER, USER, PASS)
```

Or disable SSL certificate verification (Not recommended outside of a test environment):

```
http_client.session.verify = False
```

Or as your question and answer point out, supply a local certificate store to verify against:

```
http_client.session.cert = os.environ.get('REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE')
```

From there, it's a simple matter of creating a SwaggerClient instance, pointing it to your swagger.json path, and referencing the Requests 'http_client' instance, (with pre-defined settings,) like so:

```
URL = 'https://myserver/api/path/to/swagger.json'
client = Swaggerclient.from_url(URL, http_client=http_client)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question here since I was stuck on this for a while and thought it would be nice to share what I've learned.

Since the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE env var is set, then we can create a new Requests client that's configured to use the CA Bundle. That can be passed into SwaggerClient to produce something that uses the CA Bundle when making Swagger API calls.

```
http_client = RequestsClient()
client.session.verify = os.environ.get('REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE')
client = SwaggerClient.from_url(
    reverse('grafana_generator:swaggerapi', request=request),
    http_client=http_client,
)
```